# Caption in Tikz without "Figure 1"

Tags: captions

If I use this code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol,float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% provides \preto

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={midway},
    every path/.style={fill=yellow},
    mid/.style={midway, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0,minimum size=1mm, fill=yellow,node on layer=foreground},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 4]
\draw (0.445041,0.801937) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$1$};
\draw (0.692021,0.356896) rectangle (1,1) node[mid] {$2$};
\draw (0.692021,0.356895) rectangle (0,0) node[mid] {$3$};
\draw (0.137063,0.158832) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$4$};
\draw (0.384043,0.713791) rectangle (1,0) node[mid] {$5$};
\draw (0.829084,0.515727) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$6$};
\draw (0.521105,0.872622) rectangle (0,0) node[mid] {$7$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\centering
\caption{M1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

the result as for the caption is "Figure 1: M1". Is it possible to change it
to just "M1"?

Comment: What has this got to do with TikZ? TikZ doesn't interact with figure caption titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three options; the first two, loading the `caption` package, and the third one with no packages:

1. Use `\caption*`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
   \usepackage{multicol,float}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}% provides \preto
   \usepackage{caption}

   \usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

   \tikzset{
       every node/.style={midway},
       every path/.style={fill=yellow},
       mid/.style={midway, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0,minimum size=1mm, fill=yellow},
   }

   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 4]
   \draw (0.445041,0.801937) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$1$};
   \draw (0.692021,0.356896) rectangle (1,1) node[mid] {$2$};
   \draw (0.692021,0.356895) rectangle (0,0) node[mid] {$3$};
   \draw (0.137063,0.158832) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$4$};
   \draw (0.384043,0.713791) rectangle (1,0) node[mid] {$5$};
   \draw (0.829084,0.515727) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$6$};
   \draw (0.521105,0.872622) rectangle (0,0) node[mid] {$7$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption*{M1}
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Declare the `labelformat` as `empty` using a local `\captionsetup`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
   \usepackage{multicol,float}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}% provides \preto
   \usepackage{caption}

   \usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

   \tikzset{
       every node/.style={midway},
       every path/.style={fill=yellow},
       mid/.style={midway, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0,minimum size=1mm, fill=yellow},
   }

   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}[H]
   \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 4]
   \draw (0.445041,0.801937) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$1$};
   \draw (0.692021,0.356896) rectangle (1,1) node[mid] {$2$};
   \draw (0.692021,0.356895) rectangle (0,0) node[mid] {$3$};
   \draw (0.137063,0.158832) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$4$};
   \draw (0.384043,0.713791) rectangle (1,0) node[mid] {$5$};
   \draw (0.829084,0.515727) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$6$};
   \draw (0.521105,0.872622) rectangle (0,0) node[mid] {$7$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{M1}
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
   ```
3. Don't use `\caption` at all; simply place the text:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
   \usepackage{multicol,float}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}% provides \preto

   \usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

   \tikzset{
       every node/.style={midway},
       every path/.style={fill=yellow},
       mid/.style={midway, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0,minimum size=1mm, fill=yellow},
   }

   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 4]
   \draw (0.445041,0.801937) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$1$};
   \draw (0.692021,0.356896) rectangle (1,1) node[mid] {$2$};
   \draw (0.692021,0.356895) rectangle (0,0) node[mid] {$3$};
   \draw (0.137063,0.158832) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$4$};
   \draw (0.384043,0.713791) rectangle (1,0) node[mid] {$5$};
   \draw (0.829084,0.515727) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$6$};
   \draw (0.521105,0.872622) rectangle (0,0) node[mid] {$7$};
   \end{tikzpicture}\par\medskip
   M1
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
   ```

   In this last case, if you don't want flotation, you could also simply use a `minipage` with centered content:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
   \usepackage{multicol,float}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}% provides \preto
   \usepackage{caption}

   \usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

   \tikzset{
       every node/.style={midway},
       every path/.style={fill=yellow},
       mid/.style={midway, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0,minimum size=1mm, fill=yellow},
   }

   \begin{document}

   \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 4]
   \draw (0.445041,0.801937) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$1$};
   \draw (0.692021,0.356896) rectangle (1,1) node[mid] {$2$};
   \draw (0.692021,0.356895) rectangle (0,0) node[mid] {$3$};
   \draw (0.137063,0.158832) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$4$};
   \draw (0.384043,0.713791) rectangle (1,0) node[mid] {$5$};
   \draw (0.829084,0.515727) rectangle (0,1) node[mid] {$6$};
   \draw (0.521105,0.872622) rectangle (0,0) node[mid] {$7$};
   \end{tikzpicture}\par\medskip
   M1
   \end{minipage}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: In the last case, might one not just as well replace `figure`+`\centering` with the `center` environment? (No numbered caption or label, floating disabled -> `figure` not really needed.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, but I don't know whether flotation should be removed or not in the OP's mind. I'll add a remark.

Comment: The first option is fine:-) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option (5) which is using the exact same code minus these two lines without the `\caption` command:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\end{figure}
```

Simply, `{M1}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol,float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% provides \preto

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={midway},
    every path/.style={fill=yellow},
    mid/.style={midway, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0,minimum size=1mm, fill=yellow,node on layer=foreground},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 4]
\draw (0.445041,0.801937) rectangle (0,1) node[midway] {$1$};
\draw (0.692021,0.356896) rectangle (1,1) node[midway] {$2$};
\draw (0.692021,0.356895) rectangle (0,0) node[midway] {$3$};
\draw (0.137063,0.158832) rectangle (0,1) node[midway] {$4$};
\draw (0.384043,0.713791) rectangle (1,0) node[midway] {$5$};
\draw (0.829084,0.515727) rectangle (0,1) node[midway] {$6$};
\draw (0.521105,0.872622) rectangle (0,0) node[midway] {$7$};
\end{tikzpicture}

{M1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer answer - if I remove `\begin{figure}[H]` and `\end{figure}` then the `\caption{M1}` throws an error as it's outside a float (unsurprisngly given we've just removed the `figure` environment) if this is a valid answer, please could you add an MWE to illustrate how it should work.

Comment: absolutely! edited for completion.

Comment: in addition, the provided tex encounters a problem due to the `node on layer = foreground`. the reason why i switched all node styles with just `midway`